# When is the JVM's JIT CodeCache reclaimed? Does anyone know?

Tags: jvm, jit, jvm-codecache

I recently encountered a JIT error: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled.`This caused my application to run slowly. My JDK version is Oracle JDK1.7.0_79. The default CodeCache size is 48m and I modified the size with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256M. But I don't know when CodeCache was recycled. Does anyone know?

Comment: I suppose, de-optimization and class unloading may allow reclaiming of code cache parts, but nothing else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JVM Compile Time vs Code Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316215/jvm-compile-time-vs-code-cache)

Comment: Post Java8, the code cache was segmented. So you might need adjust the XX:NonNMethodCodeHeapSize, XX:ProfiledCodeHeapSize or XX:NonProfiledCodeHeapSize . Details here: https://devtechfactory.com/blogs/java-performance-role-of-codecache